# Use the highest value for duplicate IDs (Pandas DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating the total sum of 'price' for each 'id'. But when there are duplicates on 'loc_id' it should use the highest price for calculations and ignore the lower prices for the same 'loc_id'.

The example below shows 3 duplicates for A-1. The highest price for A-1 is 100 so the total sum for A should be 100 + 200

```
df

id     loc_id    price
A        A-1        50
A        A-1        100
A        A-1        30
A        A-2        200

B        B-1        30      
B        B-2        50
```

```
df_expected_result

id      total       average
A        300        150
B        80         40
```

without the max() method, the code runs but then it double counts the loc_id duplicates. I am trying to avoid double counting. How can I make it select only the max value for each unique loc_id?

```
(df.set_index(['id','loc_id'])
  .groupby(level=0)['price']
  .max()
  .agg({'total' : np.sum , 'average' : np.average })                     
  .sort_values('total',ascending=False))
```

I get an error when I include max() method:

```
ValueError: cannot perform both aggregation and transformation operations simultaneously
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with a double `groupby()`:

```
(df.groupby(['id','loc_id'],as_index=False)['price'].max()
           .groupby('id')['price'].agg(['sum','mean']))
```

---

```
    sum  mean
id           
A   300   150
B    80    40
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df=df.sort_values(['price']).drop_duplicates(['id','loc_id'],keep='last')
df.groupby(['id']).price.agg(['mean','sum'])
Out[366]: 
    mean  sum
id           
A    150  300
B     40   80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: First getting the maximum value from the `groupby` and then finding the sum and average.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['A','A','A','A','B','B'], 'loc_id': ['A-1','A-1','A-1','A-2','B-1','B-2'], 'price':[50,100,30,200,30,50]})

df = df.groupby(['id','loc_id']).max().reset_index().groupby('id')['price']

df_new = df.sum().reset_index()

df_new['average'] = df.mean().reset_index()['price']

df_new.rename(columns={'price':'total'}, inplace=True)
df_new

  id  total  average
0  A    300      150
1  B     80       40
```